# Git commit hooks per branch

Tags: git, branch, post-commit, githooks

I'm working on getting into some more advanced usage of git, and I think hooks are the way that I want to go, perhaps somebody can give me some advice here.

My plan is to have a git repository with 3 branches (development, staging, and production).  I want commits to each of these 3 branches to trigger a different script post-commit.

Does git have the capability to do this or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In a post-commit hook you could do the following:

```
if [ `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` == "development" ]; then
   echo "development-script"
elif [ `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` == "staging" ]; then
   echo "staging-script"
elif [ `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` == "production" ]; then
   echo "production-script"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I had written a script for myself to do this functionality.

https://github.com/fotuzlab/githubdump-php

Host this file on your server, preferably repo root and define the url in github webhooks. Change 'allcommits' on line 8 with your branch name and add your code/function at line 18.

You will need separate files and webhooks for all your 3 instances.