# Using git post-receive hook to deploy python application in virtualenv

Tags: python, django, git, virtualenv, githooks

My goal is to be able to deploy a Django application to one of two environments (DEV or PROD) based on the Git branch that was committed and pushed to a repository. This repository is hosted on the same server as the Django applications are being run on.

Right now, I have two `virtualenv`s set up. One for each environment. They are identical. I envision them only changing if the `requirements.txt` is modified in my repository.

I've seen tutorials around the internet that offer deployments via `git` by hosting the repository directly in the location where the application will be deployed. This doesn't work for my architecture. I'm using RhodeCode to host/manage the repository. I'd like to be able to use a post-receive (or other if it's more appropriate) hook to trigger the update to the appropriate environment.

Something similar to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351551/writing-a-git-post-receive-hook-to-deal-with-a-specific-branch/13057643#13057643) will allow me to narrow down which environment I want to focus on.

When I put `source activate` command in an external script (ie. my hook), the script stops at that command. The `virtualenv` is started appropriately, but any further actions in the script (ie. `pip install -r requirements.txt` or `./manage.py migrate`) aren't executed.

My question, is how can I have that hook run the associated `virtualenv`? Or, if it is already running, update it appropriately with the new `requirements.txt`, `South` migrations, and application code?

Is this work flow overly complicated? Theoretically, it should be as simple as `git push` to the appropriate branch.

Comment: why dont you use a fabfile that connects to the server and pulls the new code