# GIT Workflow - with dev and staging environments

Tags: git

I'm a newbie to git and have been looking and some workflows. I found [this](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) and really like it but I do have some questions.

I've set up a post receive hook on the master that updates a production server with all of the latest changes, however, I'm wondering how to handle dev and/or staging environments.

Is there a way to update subdomains on the server (ie: dev.mydomain.com, staging.mydomain.com) based on branch changes without having to maintain multiple repos for one project? If I push and only the develop branch changed, it would be great to update dev.mydomain.com. If I'm pushing changes to release branches, staging.mydomain.com would ideally update.

Also - I'm not using github. We have this setup on our own CentOS server with WHM/CPanel if any of that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you cannot do this. You should be able to grab the name of the branch that was just pushed ([Writing a git post-receive hook to deal with a specific branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351551/writing-a-git-post-receive-hook-to-deal-with-a-specific-branch)) and then deploy from the shell script.

Comment: This is ultimately the approach I ended up going with. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One sane way to do it would be to clone the repository to the webdir of each of the subdomains, checkout the appropriate branches there, and configure your git hook to update these repositories whenever something is pushed.

Comment: That seems sane. The only "issue" I have with it is managing multiple repositories. Maybe I don't understand git well enough, but I would think it would get a little cumbersome to switch repos... whereas switching branches would be more streamlined.

Comment: Well, that management of multiple repositories would be handled by your git hook script, so it wouldn’t create you any hassle during the normal development process. The hook would do something like `cd /var/www/staging; git pull` etc. (maybe a little more sophisticated if you like, but that’s the principle.)

Answer (score 1):

Git itself only provides the Repository structure and how Developers work together. For different Stages you should add cloned Projects, because they are supposed to diverge. Maintaining them is an important task, you can simply do this by hand or Write some Bash scripts, or even some CLI Programms for that. Maybe the Panel you are using, does provide some API calls. GitLab for Example has an API to automaticly do this kind of Stuff.

After that, all that matters is Timing it with an Cron Job or an Interface. :)

Comment: I haven't found anything with regards to API calls for CPanel. I think they just added the functionality of git to the system.

Comment: Then you simply have something like a Deployment Server, where you hold your master Instances for the Repositorys. Its the central point, where everyone has to compare with each other, like merging stuff. Then you need a User on the Server that is allowed to do all git Actions. What you want to do, is getting an Idea how to Deploy it manualy, and then you can automate this with scripts that perform Git Commands. Deploying one system to another Stage can simply be done by replacing it. But be carefull with that, you can also define different States of a Project as Branches.