# git: getting branch name in post-receive hook fails after debian wheezy upgrade

Tags: git, deployment, hook

I deploying my app directly from git by post-receive hook.
First time I detect branch name then my script do deploy to corresponding path.
I using branch detection method described there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12367999/3877101

Everything works fine until my server must be upgraded to Debian 7 Wheezy.
Nowadays I can see this error in git push log:

*remote: hooks/post-receive: 6: read: Illegal option -a

remote: hooks/post-receive: 9: hooks/post-receive: Syntax error: redirection unexpected*

Hook fails inside the if statement (line 6 in my code), but this statement will be true whether STDIN isn't provided (! -t 0 according to docs).
I'm out of ideas, can you help?

EDIT: My code for getting branch name

```
5 if ! [ -t 0 ]; then
6  read -a ref
7 fi
8
9 IFS='/' read -ra REF <<< "${ref[2]}"
10 branch="${REF[2]}"
```

Comment: Try posting the code where it fails !

Comment: You should definitely include the failing code in your question. Maybe you have a restricted shell or something. `read -a ref` should be valid in bash.

Comment: Code is the same as described at another stackoverflow question (linked). But code added.