# Git post-receive hook for push-to-deploy .. I want to checkout last pushed branch

Tags: git, deployment, githooks, git-push

I am able to implement push-to-deploy with Git by creating a bare repo on the server, and pushing to that from my dev. Below is my post-receive which handles updating the live site:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo
echo "*** Checking out branch [post-receive hook]"
echo

git --work-tree=/var/www/myproject checkout -f master
```

Notice that it checkouts "master" branch this works great in most cases. "master" is the branch I push (e.g. `git push staging master` when pushing to live to the staging server). However, I sometimes like to push a branch only without merging my changes to master (e.g. `git push staging new-register-form`). Can I change my post-receive hook script to checkout "the last pushed branch"? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)
    git --work-tree=/var/www/myproject checkout -f $branch
done
```

taken from: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13057643)