# Prevent merging branch into master if it contains commits with specific text

Tags: git, git-merge

My workflow: I have a master branch and a feature branch. When I'm done with the feature, I merge-squash it into master (then push master to remote, though not immediately, I may work on other features first).

When working on a feature branch I often leave comments like `//TODO ...` to remind me to do something. For simplicity, I include them in commits (I'm going to merge squash, so they shouldn't appear in master anyway). But sometimes I forget to clean those comments before finishing up the feature, and so they find their way into master.

I read about "pre-commit hooks", but I don't think that helps me because I don't want to prevent committing those lines in a feature branch. What I want to is to *prevent merging into master if the feature branch contains those lines*.

Is this possible? (And, is it possible using git alone, without a third-party script / tool?)

Answer (score 1):

I believe [pre-merge-commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_merge_commit) is what you're looking for

A sample script is given [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/templates/hooks--pre-merge-commit.sample):

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# An example hook script to verify what is about to be committed.
# Called by "git merge" with no arguments.  The hook should
# exit with non-zero status after issuing an appropriate message to
# stderr if it wants to stop the merge commit.
#
# To enable this hook, rename this file to "pre-merge-commit".

. git-sh-setup
test -x "$GIT_DIR/hooks/pre-commit" &&
        exec "$GIT_DIR/hooks/pre-commit"
:
```

I believe you should be able to use `grep` or any other method to recursively search through what would be the result of the merge as it's written:

`It takes no parameters, and is invoked after the merge has been carried out successfully and before obtaining the proposed commit log message to make a commit.`

You can also [get the two branches from stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351551/writing-a-git-post-receive-hook-to-deal-with-a-specific-branch) and use them as input in your script to only perform this if the merge is occurring from feature to master

Comment: Thank you! Do you think this works with a fast forward merge as well, because it doesn't seem to work for me?

Comment: @lonix Fast forward is not a merge at all so merge hooks are not triggered.

Comment: @phd Thanks for confirming. I setup the hook as explained above, but when I do `git merge --squash feature-branch; git commit` the hook isn't called, and the output mentions that a FF was done. So is this hook not applicable to my use case, or have I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: @lonix Squash merge is also not a merge, IMO it's the worst kind of merges and I avoid it. To trigger a merge hook you need a real merge: `git merge --no-ff`

Comment: @phd Alright I understand, so this hook doesn't apply to me - thanks for explaining! However your comment about disliking "squashing" commits (and so I assume you disapprove of my workflow mentioned above) is going to send me down a rabbit hole of research... thanks no thanks! :-P

Comment: @lomix For your use case, the best I can see is https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_merge which isn't able to abort the merge, but can at least inform you that a TODO comment is still there, and can maybe be called to revert to before the merge.

Comment: @eeegnu Thanks for the tip I'll look into that option as well.