# are git hooks global within a repository

Tags: git, version-control

I have a git pre-commit hook that checks pep8 compliance, and I want to add it to repositories which have multiple branches already. If I add it to `.git/hooks/` on one branch will that hook be present in other branches or is each branches .git folder unique? I want to add the hook to master and have it present in all other branches. Will this require manually replacing it on each branch or can I add it to one branch and have it present in all of them?

Comment: What kind of hook is that? Pre-commit, pre-receive ? Post-commit?

Comment: it's a pre-commit hook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be active within the repository for all branches. In case of `pre-commit` hook, all your local branches will have this hook activated before committing stuff.

It will not be active for other repositories, unless it's `pre-receive`/`post-receive` (which are [server-side hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks) that activate on push to repository where the hook is installed).

I tried to find out some documentation to support my statement, but frankly I didn't. Here's some [documentation on hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Client-Side-Hooks), but it doesn't tell it outright, that hooks are all common for all branches.

It's pretty straightforward though, because `.git` directory is unique within whole repository and it is not subject to versioning, it's not a part of the code. When you change hook script it is not visible in `not staged changes`.

Most people have the opposite problem - to differentiate hooks behavior depending on branch, like Eugene in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372334/git-commit-hooks-per-branch).